# Permissions error "container.secrets.list" deploying to GKE from github-actions using helm

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, service-accounts

I'm trying to use helm from my github actions runner to deploy to my GKE cluster but I'm running into a permissions error.

Using a google cloud service account for authentication

**GitHub Actions CI step**

```
      - name: Install gcloud cli
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
        with:
          version: latest
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID }}
          service_account_email: ${{ secrets.GCLOUD_SA_EMAIL }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCLOUD_SA_KEY }}
          export_default_credentials: true

      - name: gcloud configure
        run: |
          gcloud config set project ${{secrets.GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}};
          gcloud config set compute/zone ${{secrets.GCLOUD_COMPUTE_ZONE}};
          gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${{secrets.GCLOUD_CLUSTER_NAME}};

      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          ***
          helm upgrade *** ./helm \
            --install \
            --debug \
            --reuse-values \
            --set-string "$overrides"
```

**The error**

```
history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release blog
Error: query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "***" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default": requires one of ["container.secrets.list"] permission(s).
helm.go:88: [debug] secrets is forbidden: User "***" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default": requires one of ["container.secrets.list"] permission(s).
```

Comment: What roles/permissions did you assign to the Google Service Account?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to deploy code by using the GKE **viewer role** , hence your getting the permission issue. You can create the required **IAM policies** and **role based access control (RBAC)** as per your [requirement](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/access-control).

You can also check kubernetes engine roles and responsibilities by using this [reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles).